# Multiple create operation request

Tags: web-services, rest, design-patterns, soap, concurrency

Is there a standard design pattern to solve multiple concurrent create requests on the server? 
For eg) multiple clients (from browsers/mobile) can call the webservice to create an appointment for a doctor for a given time. Though, webservice can initially check if the doctor is free and then create, still there is a race condition and might end up creating multiple appointments in the backend. How do we stop the server from creating multiple appointments ? Given the webservice runs on mulitple servers and the appointments dont have any fixed timing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of any patterns. One idea I can think of.

1) Add a check to see if the appointment already exists:

```
  if Appointment.where(time:, docter_id:).exists? 
      raise 'appointment already exists'
  else
      create_appointment
```

The above have the possibility to pass the not exists check and end up duplicate appointments because of the nature of concurrency. Two options possible for this problem,

i) Enforce the check at the DB constraints level. Unique index of docter_id, appointment_time could be good start. If a error is raised handle it as it is already existing. It is good to enforce the constraints logic at the DB level to ensure consistency from app/scripts to update DB records.

ii) Second option I can think of pessimistic locking of the table for the transaction- which I wouldn't suggest to create a record.